# How to call method from another class in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, class, methods, label

I have 2 classes. 1st one is Label, another one is LabelGestureRecognizer. In the LabelGestureRecognizer have a method called getName, and i want call the method through the Label class.

Below is a simple example of my problem.
I am trying to call the method 'getName', but I am getting an error saying:
“No visible @interface for 'LabelGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'getName:'”

ViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *valueLabel;
```

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    valueLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 366, 320, 50)];
    valueLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    valueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:valueLabel]; 
}

- (void) wheelDidChangeValue:(NSString *) newValue {
    self.valueLabel.text = newValue;
}
```

Label.h:

```
@protocol LabelDelegate <NSObject> 
@required
 -(void) wheelDidChangeValue:(NSString *) newValue;
@end

@class LabelGestureRecognizer;
```

LabelGestureRecognizer.m:

```
- (NSString *) getName:(int) position
{
    NSString *resultat = @"";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resultat = @"Test 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            resultat = @"Test 2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

LabelGestureRecognizer.h:

```
 @interface LabelGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
 {
     NSDate *previous;
     double current;
 }
```

Label.m:

```
 LabelGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[LabelGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
 [self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[self getName:0]];
```

Comment: *" I have a class called Label.m, and i want to call a method, called getName from LabelGestureRecognizer class."* This looks like a bit confusing statement. As per the example, `getName` is in `LabelGestureRecognizer` and you are trying to call from `Label` class. But your statement says the reverse. Which is correct?

Comment: I think the error messages "No visible @interface for 'LabelGestureRecognizer' declares the selector 'getName:" clearly states that you havent declared the getName method in your .h file. Can you add the .h file code to the question. I am sure that you haven't declared it there or declared with a wrong signature.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the above .h file. Please check with that and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `self` in `Label.m`, that represents the current class object. If you need to represent `LabelGestureRecognizer` object, you need to use that in place of `self` as,

```
[self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[recognizer getName:0]];
```

Also you should declare the following in your `LabelGestureRecognizer.h` file as,

```
@interface LabelGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer
 {
     NSDate *previous;
     double current;
 }
- (NSString *) getName:(int) position;
@end
```

Your error message is saying that it is not able to see the declaration of `getName` method in `LabelGestureRecognizer.h` class file.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons it could happen, but generally it's saying that at the line of code it flags, it doesn't see any evidence that the selector you are referencing is in the interface of the type it thinks the object has.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the selector in the interface of LabelGestureRecognizer.h

```
 @interface
 - (NSString *) getName:(int) position;
 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can simply create an instance of class by alloc class and call the method and after use it you can release

```
LabelGestureRecognizer *labelGestureRecognizer = [[LabelGestureRecognizer alloc] init];

[self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[labelGestureRecognizer getName:0]];
[labelGestureRecognizer release];
```

But as your code i will suggest to create Class Method

```
+ (NSString *) getName:(int) position
{
    NSString *resultat = @"";
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resultat = @"Test 1";
            break;
        case 1:
            resultat = @"Test 2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return resultat;
}
```

and you can get value by

```
 [self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[LabelGestureRecognizer getName:0]];
```

For more about class method you can follow this link [Writing Objective-C Class Methods](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_Objective-C_Class_Methods)

Comment: [self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[LabelGestureRecognizer getName:0]];  I am getting an error saying: "No known class method for slector -getName'"

Comment: did you changed the class method sign from - to + ?? and import LabelGestureRecognizer in you class

Comment: update your interface (.h) file also

+ (NSString *) getName:(int) position;

Comment: @abhishekkharwar, +1. Not a bad suggestion, even though it has nothing to do with the question. Usage of classname is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just create object of that class in which that method is,and finally call the method with that object.Pretty simple...